# How to execute one TFS 2010 build script from other TFS 2010 build script

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am having two separate build script written in TFS 2010. One is for application and other is for wcf service. I need to execute service build script from application's build scripts. Could someone please suggest how could I achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how you have this setup at the moment? Are these two `.proj` files? Are you currently using one or two build definitions? Do you need to results from one build in the other? Simply triggering another build can be accomplished by calling `tfsbuild start` on a commandline, but going beyond starting is not a supported scenario. In that case you're better off building both solutions in a single build definition.

Comment: Thanks.. I am having two .proj files and executing both the files separately. I don't need result of one script into other. The main intend is to execute both the build as a bundle. Basically I want to do build chaining.

Answer (score 2):

To simply trigger one build after finishing another, you can use the `tfsbuild` utility that is installed on a system when you install Team Explorer.

You should be able to call it using

```
<Exec Command="$(VS140COMNTOOLS)\..\IDE\tfsbuild.exe start $(TeaFoundationServerUrl) $(TeamProject) DefinitionName" />
```

check [the additional parameters here in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181742(v=vs.100).aspx).

A list of useful environment variables available can be found here: http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html

Do note that the `.proj` files to orchestarte your builds are ancient (from the 2008 era) and have long since been outdated first by XAML builds and later by the new 2015 Build engine.

Team Foundation Server 2010 itself is no longer supported by Microsoft since June last year.